# php class return array

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I tried to get followers from `MySQL` usingy this class

```
class get_followers {
    public $followers_arr = array();
    public function __construct($user_id) {
        $query = "select * from followsystem where following ='$user_id'";

        $q = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

        $count = mysql_num_rows($q);

        if ($count > 0) {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
                array_push($this->followers_arr, $row['userid']);
           }
        }

        return $this->followers_arr;
    }
}
```

Then I initialize this class

```
$fol = new get_followers($userid);
$fol_arr = json_encode($fol);
echo $fol_arr;
```

Then I get

```
{"followers_arr":["1234","456"]}
```

but what i want want just to get this

```
["1234","456"]
```

How is that works?

Comment: Do not `json_encode($fol);`

Comment: Try: `print_r($fol->followers_arr);` and remove the `$fol_arr = json_encode($fol);` just to: `$fol_arr = $fol;`

Comment: First of all it's not `OOP` even though you are creating object. Read some more about that.

Comment: $fol = new get_followers($userid);
 $fol_arr = json_encode($fol->followers_arr);

  echo $fol_arr;

it works when i did this thank you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you understand how constructors work. You can't return a value from a constructor because it's just used to instantiate the object. When you're doing `$fol_arr = json_encode($fol);` you're actually encoding the entire object, not it's return value.

If you really want to use a class to do this, you should add a method to the class and use that, like this:

```
class Followers {
    public $followers_arr = array();
    public $user_id = null;

    public function __construct($user_id) {
        $this->user_id = $user_id;            
    }

    public function get()
    {
        $query = "select * from followsystem where following ='{$this->user_id}'";

        $q = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

        $count = mysql_num_rows($q);

        if ($count > 0) {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
                array_push($this->followers_arr, $row['userid']);
           }
        }

        return $this->followers_arr;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
$fol = new Followers($userid);
$fol_arr = json_encode($fol->get());
echo $fol_arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is to do `$fol_arr = json_encode($fol->followers_arr);`

Nonetheless, making a class in this case is completely obsolete, since you only make it as a wrapper for a single function you want to execute (called `get_followers`) Instead of making a class, you could simply make the following:

```
function get_followers($user_id) {
        $followers_arr = [];
        $query = "select * from followsystem where following ='$user_id'";

        $q = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

        $count = mysql_num_rows($q);

        if ($count > 0) {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
                array_push($followers_arr, $row['userid']);
           }
        }

        return $followers_arr;

}

$fol = get_followers($userid);
$fol_arr = json_encode($fol);
echo $fol_arr;
```

There is no need to put it in a class unless the class serves the purpose of combining a few functions and variables to create a behaviour.